# Response time too long Oracle Apex 4.2 RESTful WebService

Tags: oracle, web-services, rest, oracle-apex, latency

I need to consume web services within my apex Apps, i tried sample app from here: [Apex S3 Demo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/integration-086636.html#S3) it worked, but response time is about **15 seconds**, then i tried another with Google Geocode API [Apex Google Geocode Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QaTZlRNt-R4) and again time is **15-16 seconds**. It's normal response time from Apex Web Services or is there something to do?

Comment: So did you implement the solutions on a system locally or on apex.oracle.com? Did you run a debug to see what is eating those seconds away?

Comment: It is local instance. Apex Listener and Apex Instance are running on separate server. So i noticed that WebService need Apex Instance server to have accsess to Internet. I don't understand why it's required.

Comment: Here is debug result: "...0.01280 15.15440 ...Process "Web Service Request" - Type: WEB_SERVICE..."

Comment: Could you add a more comprehensive log of your debug in your post perhaps? A screenshot maybe even? If it does take 15 seconds that is very long, but I doubt it is database related. When you have the google geocode service and you test it from the webservice references, does it take as long? Have you tried to run the service from another program such as (eg) SoapUI? Does it take 15 seconds there too?

Comment: Hi @Tom , in the Amazon S3 case i've tested the same service usign S3Fox Organizer [link](http://www.s3fox.net), and it work very well (fast response).

Comment: Here is some Debug information: [Apex Debug](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1e015aFCLEDbFFMLUJTNjR1Q2M/edit?usp=sharing), [Chrome Developers Tool](http://i41.tinypic.com/2h4hvuh.png)

Comment: sorry for the late response. Honestly-I don't really know. It does indeed take 15 seconds but there is no real way for us to determine where those go. I would talk to a network admin who can take a look at it, or ask the dba to run the request from the db machine through a tool such as soapui and see if it also take 15 seconds. There is ultimately still a big difference between your local machine and the database machine (which is where the call originates from)

Comment: Thank you Tom, my project is stucked here because this problem, anyway i will try anothers configurations in other of isolate this cause.